# Custom Vagrant command with a plugin

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm trying to add a couple of custom commands to a Vagrantfile so I can use `vagrant <cmd>` instead of cluttering the project folder with a ton of extra scripts.

Is there a way to do this without uploading a gem?  Specifically, it'd be ideal if once the project is checked out from git the commands work out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this in 2016 or later, vagrant now supports:

```
vagrant YOUR-COMMAND
```

See "[PLUGIN DEVELOPMENT: COMMANDS](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/commands.html)" for details:

> Within the context of a plugin definition . . . Commands are defined with the `command` method, which takes as an argument the name of the command, in this case "foo." This means the command will be invokable via `vagrant foo`.

```
command "foo" do
  require_relative "command"
  Command
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and discovered [this thread](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3775). I really like [agoebel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2004975/agoebel)'s solution, but hijacking the `Vagrantfile` seems a little hacky and still doesn't introduce custom commands. I see this approach is being appropriate for checking plugin dependences, or some additional check before standard commands are run:

```
REQUIRED_PLUGINS = %w(vagrant-ohai vagrant-vbguest)
restart_required = REQUIRED_PLUGINS.any? do |plugin|
  system "vagrant plugin install #{plugin}" unless Vagrant.has_plugin?(plugin)
end
```

But you can also create a file in the same directory as your `Vargrantfile` called `.vagrantplugins` which a plugin definition like so:

```
class MyCommand < Vagrant.plugin(2, :command)
  def self.synopsis
    "Says Hello"
  end

  def execute
    puts "Hello"
    0
  end
end

class MyPlugin < Vagrant.plugin(2)
  name "My Plugin"

  command "mycommand" do
    MyCommand
  end
end
```

Effectively allowing you to write custom commands. Vagrant removed the functionality that allowed definition of custom commands inline in new 2.x.x version of the API.

This is a great compromise. If you `vagrant list-commands`, you should see:

```
mycommand       Says Hello
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

So, while it isn't a full "vagrant command" it seems I can hijack the script as long as I `exit` before `Vagrant.configure`.  Seems hacky but it should work fine, at least to redirect two simple commands.  Doesn't help to hook into the vagrant info though so this isn't ideal.

Comment: I really like this approach because it's simple, straightforward, and highly portable. I keep getting the `Usage: vagrant [options] <command> [<args>]` prompt when calling `vagrant` with a parameter it doesn't recognize, though.